# Not show hamburger button in androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android-toolbar, androidx

In Android Studio 3.4.1

in app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

In gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

In activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainNavigationDrawerFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                mToolbar, R.string.application_name,
                R.string.application_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                mToolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                mToolbar.setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                loadDraftsTotalNumber();
                loadActiveCart();
            }
        };
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"/>
<style name="Main.Theme.Tango" parent="AppBaseTheme"/>
```

in my main layout:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                           android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                           android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    />

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>


    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="288dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:paddingLeft="16dip"
            android:paddingRight="16dip"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But hamburger button is not show in toolbar:

[image]